# Data not being preserved in autoit

Tags: autoit

I am using one file to send data to global variables in a globals file and having another file try and retrieve that data from the globals file after.

Example:

Main file sends data to global file and other file gets data from global file

For some reason the data isn't being preserved. When I pull the data from the global file it's not there. Why is this?

Here is some example code:

```
;main.au3
#include-once
#include "global.au3"


$g1 = "stuff"
$g2 = "stuff"

Run("copy.exe")

;global.au3
#include-once

Global $g1 = ""
Global $g2 = ""

;copy.au3
#include-once
#include "global.au3"

MsgBox(0, $g1, $g2)
```

main.au3 and copy.au3 have been built into .exe and I double click on main to run it.

The result: $g1 and $g2 are equal to "" and "" when it should be printing "stuff"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `global.au3` doesn't get updated. It's providing initial values to your variables. Using `#include "global.au3"` is the same as writing:

```
;main.au3
#include-once
Global $g1 = ""
Global $g2 = ""

$g1 = "stuff"
$g2 = "stuff"

Run("copy.exe")
```

and

```
;copy.au3
#include-once
Global $g1 = ""
Global $g2 = ""

MsgBox(0, $g1, $g2)
```

As you can see, `copy.au3` (`copy.exe`) has `$g1` and `$g2` set to `""`.

To pass your `$g1` and `$g2` variables to `copy.exe`, you can either use `IniRead()/IniWrite()` to read/write an .ini file or pass the variables as command line parameters.

Here's an example of the command line parameters option:

(no global.au3 needed;
compile main.au3 and copy.au3;
double click main.exe to run)

**main.au3**

```
;main.au3

$g1 = "stuff"
$g2 = "stuff"

ShellExecute('copy.exe', $g1 & ' ' & $g2)
```

**copy.au3**

```
;copy.au3

$g1 = $CmdLine[1]
$g2 = $CmdLine[2]

MsgBox(0, $g1, $g2)
```

I used `ShellExecute()` instead of `Run()` because `Run()` has been a pain in the a$$ in the past (for me). I don't usually have any issues with `ShellExecute()` and `ShellExecuteWait()`.

Also, for more info on command line parameters you can search on "Command Line Parameters" in the AutoIt help.